# MVVM data binding to new object instance

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone, mvvm-light

I'm using MVVMlight in windows phone. The model is bound via xaml through the locator. The view model loads a new instance of the model from a webrequest then assigns it. I'm not sure why the view is not being updated, is it because its a new instance being assigned? If I update a property of the model instead of assigning a new instance, it updates on the view.

How do I update the view when assigning a new instance of the model?

View Model:

```
public class MyViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public MyModel Model { get; set; }

    public MyViewModel ()
    {
        if (IsInDesignMode)
        {
        }
        else
        {
            //async call
            api.GetModel(response =>
                                 Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke
                                     (() =>
                                          {
                                              //this works.
                                              //Model.Property1 = "Some Text";
                                              //this doesn't work
                                              Model = response.Data;

                                          }
                                     ));
        }
    }
}
```

View.xaml

```
<UserControl x:Class="Grik.WindowsPhone.CardDetailsView"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    DataContext="{Binding MyModel, Source={StaticResource Locator}}" >

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" >
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Model.Property1}" />

    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: Shouldn't there be a `RaisePropertyChanged` in the Setter for the `Model` property?

Comment: @NeilTurner yes, it has it, and it works when the property changes. When a new instance is assigned however, it seems like all that binding was removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would like to see your code in View Model Locator class

In MyViewModel class you may need to rewrite this property

```
public MyModel Model { get; set; }
```

to

```
private MyModel _model; 
public MyModel Model { 
get{return this._model;}
set{
    this._model = value;
    this.NotifyPropertyChanged("Model");
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the ViewModel does not implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface.
The `MyModel` as well as all of its properties need to use the property changed event as well.

You show you use `Model.Property1` in the xaml, `Model.Property1` needs to also raise the property changed event.

```
public class MyModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _Property1 = "";

     public string Property1
    {
        get { return this._Property1; }

        set
        {
            if (value != this._Property1)
            {
                this._Property1 = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }      
}
```

Comment: That is exactly how `MyModel` is designed, and it works when the property changes, it just needs some kind of rebinding when a new instance is assigned, which I have no idea how to do from the ViewModel

Comment: Do the same thing with the MyModel..

private MyModel _Model = "";

     public MyModel Model 
    {
        get
        {
            return this._Model;
        }

        set
        {
            if (value != this._Model)
            {
                this._Model = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

    }

Comment: Also you set your datacontext specifically an item from the ViewModel.. You would normally set the datacontext to the viewmodel and each control on the view would have its datacontext set to an item in the viewmodel. the view now only has context of the model and not the viewmodel.

Comment: I'm sure that ViewModelBase class has INotifyProperyChanged interface impelemented he is just not using it.